# Windows batch with IF condition

Tags: batch-file, automation

I am trying to do a window batch file as the automation for my workflow. At first I did an example with this and it works:

```
@echo off
set /p answer=Are you a boy (Y/N)?

if /i "%answer%" == "Y" (
echo Yes, I am a boy.
)

if /i "%answer%" == "N" (
echo No, I am a girl.
)

echo end....
```

Then I try to do it with my automation:

```
@echo off
echo. -------Default Settings--------
echo APP_DEBUG=true
echo DB_HOST=localhost
echo DB_USERNAME=root
echo DB_PASSWORD=
echo. -------------------------------
set /p question="Use the default settings? [Y/N]: "
if /i "%question%" == "N" (
    echo Configure custom setting
    set /p APP_DEBUG="APP_DEBUG: "
    set /p DB_HOST="DB_HOST: "
    set /p DB_USERNAME="DB_USERNAME: "
    set /p DB_PASSWORD="DB_PASSWORD: "
}
if /i "%question%" == "Y" (
    set APP_DEBUG=true
    set DB_HOST=localhost
    set DB_USERNAME=root
    set DB_PASSWORD=
    echo default settings
)
echo done
```

The problem is it just end the execution after asking for the input. What I have done wrong? How to get it works (if possible without using `goto`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accidentally used a bracket to close your first `if` statement rather than a closing parenthesis.

Change:

```
if /i "%question%" == "N" (
 echo Configure custom setting
 set /p APP_DEBUG="APP_DEBUG: "
 set /p DB_HOST="DB_HOST: "
 set /p DB_USERNAME="DB_USERNAME: "
 set /p DB_PASSWORD="DB_PASSWORD: "
}
```

To:

```
if /i "%question%" == "N" (
 echo Configure custom setting
 set /p APP_DEBUG="APP_DEBUG: "
 set /p DB_HOST="DB_HOST: "
 set /p DB_USERNAME="DB_USERNAME: "
 set /p DB_PASSWORD="DB_PASSWORD: "
)
```

Also, i would use `choice` in this situation as it doesn't require the user to hit enter to submit the input:

```
@echo off
echo. -------Default Settings--------
echo APP_DEBUG=true
echo DB_HOST=localhost
echo DB_USERNAME=root
echo DB_PASSWORD=
echo. -------------------------------
choice /C:yn /n /m "Use the default settings? [Y/N]: "
if errorlevel==2 (
  echo Configure custom setting
  set /p APP_DEBUG="APP_DEBUG: "
  set /p DB_HOST="DB_HOST: "
  set /p DB_USERNAME="DB_USERNAME: "
  set /p DB_PASSWORD="DB_PASSWORD: "
) else (
  set APP_DEBUG=true
  set DB_HOST=localhost
  set DB_USERNAME=root
  set DB_PASSWORD=
  echo default settings
)
echo done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your tip about `choice`. Something new to learn.

Comment: No problem, happy programming! :D